# I want to move items within a two dimentional array in Java

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

I am making a backgammon game and I have the board setup using a 2D array like so:

```
stoneCounts[0][0]=stoneCounts[0][1]=stoneCounts[0][2]=stoneCounts[0][3]=stoneCounts[0][4] = W; 
stoneCounts[11][0]=stoneCounts[11][1] = W;
stoneCounts[16][0]=stoneCounts[16][1]=stoneCounts[16][2]= W;
stoneCounts[18][0]=stoneCounts[18][1]=stoneCounts[18][2]=stoneCounts[18][3]=stoneCounts[18][4]=W;
stoneCounts[23][0]=stoneCounts[23][1]=stoneCounts[23][2]=stoneCounts[23][3]=stoneCounts[23][4] =B;
stoneCounts[12][0]=stoneCounts[12][1] = B;
stoneCounts[7][0]=stoneCounts[7][1]=stoneCounts[7][2]=stoneCounts[7][3]=stoneCounts[7][4] =B;
stoneCounts[5][0]=stoneCounts[5][1]=stoneCounts[5][2]=  B;
```

When a player makes a move, how can I get the, for eg. 'W' at stoneCounts[0][1] to move to stoneCounts[2][3]

Comment: stoneCounts[2][3]=stoneCounts[0][1] ?

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you also have an `E` which represents an empty square. Then all you have to do is (assuming the new square is already empty):

```
 stoneCounts[2][3] = stoneCounts[0][1];
 stoneCounts[0][1] = E;
```

In other words, just copy the status of the old square to the new square (and remember to somehow clear the status of the old square.)